# inserting values without having to format them specifically like the training model

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

My plan was to insert only 2 values (The Gold and S&P closing price) into a Machine Learning model (linear regression model of Sklearn) and then daily download the opening values of the S&P and Gold, and predict the closing price that BTC would have according to these values. The model works perfectly and predicts the values right 99% right of the time.

Here's the problem:

I want to only input the single values into the prediction algorithm, but I can't seem to work out how to input values without having to convert them to np.arrays and finally the classic sklearn format with
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.1)

Does anyone know how to convert the values to the right format without having to use this line of code?

I simply want to be able to use:

Prediction_of_today = linear.predict(!some format of downloaded closing prices of Gold and S&P!)

print(Prediction of today)

```
 import yfinance as yf
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import sklearn
    import time
    from sklearn import model_selection
    from sklearn import linear_model
    import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
    from matplotlib import style
    import pickle

'''downloading the right format of values'''
'''use yfinance as my API '''


#donwload and rename relevant columns 
BTC = yf.download(tickers='BTC-USD', period="16wk", interval='1d')
BTC_.rename(columns={'Adj Closing': 'BTC closing'}, inplace=True)

SaP = yf.download('SPY', period="16wk", interval="1d")
SaP.rename(columns={'Open':'S&P opening'}, inplace=True)

Gold = yf.download('GC=F', period="16wk", interval="1d")
Gold.rename(columns={'Open':'Gold opening'}, inplace=True)

btc_closing = BTC['BTC closing']
btc_closing = pd.Series(btc_closing, index=SaP.index)
gold_opening = Gold['Gold opening']
gold_opening = pd.Series(gold_opening, index=SaP.index)
sap_opening = SaP['S&P opening']


add_input_data = pd.concat([gold_opening, sap_opening], axis=1)
full_data = pd.concat([add_input_data, btc_closing], axis=1)


corr_SB = sap_opening.corr(btc_closing)
corr_GB = gold_opening.corr(btc_closing)

print(f'The correlation of the SaP to BTC is {corr_SB}, the correlation of Gold to BTC amounts to {corr_GB}')


full_data = full_data.rename(columns={"Adj Close": "BTC closing"})


X = np.array(full_data.drop(['BTC closing'], 1))
y = np.array(full_data['BTC closing'])

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.1)

linear = linear_model.LinearRegression()
linear.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Please **fix your indentation**.

Comment: You exact question is pretty unclear; what does `train_test_split` even have to do here? This is used only once during data preparation for model fitting. Please **clarify exactly** what your issue is.

Comment: I guess I thought that the format of the inputs would change by using the test train split etc 

If that isn't the case then excuse me please

Comment: Please notice that the point is not to apologize, the point is to *clarify exactly* what your issue is (still unclear).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to input a single value, you need to ensure the format of the input is your single value inside a list, because what you input is a list of a dataset. e.g. Prediction_of_today = linear.predict([[],[],[],[],...]). Therefore, if the dataset only include one single value, it may look like Prediction_of_today = linear.predict([[]])

Hope it is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I misuderstood the concept

for clarification:

i could simply format the values as np.array and use it to predict the needed value!

this is what I was looking for

```
test_data = pd.concat([gold_closing_test, sap_closing_test], axis=1)

test_data = np.array(test_data)

prediction_results = linear.predict(test_data)
```